# How to evaluate multiple if conditions in java

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

I have a complicated data structure (called twoDim) as follows

```
[[Bolus Exposure (Impedance)Upright], [,  Recumbent, Total], [,  Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total], [Normal], [Acid Time,  11.0 min, 0.0 min, 11.0 min], ]
[[Acid Exposure (pH),  Upright], [Recumbent, Total], [,  Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total], [Normal], [Clearance pH  :  Channel 7]]
[[Postprandial Data], [,  Postprandial Interval:  120 min]]
[[Reflux Study Summary], [Acid Exposure (pH),  Upright, Recumbent, Total], [,  Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total], ]]
```

I would like to extract just the `[[Acid Exposure (pH),  Upright], [Recumbent, Total], [,  Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total], [Normal], [Clearance pH  :  Channel 7]]`

The extraction should be based on the fact that "Recumbent" is the first element in one of the inner arrays.

My code:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList> AcidExpMain = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList> temp = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
         Pattern tu1 = Pattern.compile("Acid Exposure \\(pH\\)");
         Pattern tu2 = Pattern.compile("Recumbent");

    for (List<String> row : twoDim) {

                 if (tu1.matcher(row.get(0)).matches() && tu2.matcher(row.get(0)).matches()) {
                     AcidExpMain.add((ArrayList<List<String>>) twoDim);
                     System.out.println("Success");

                 }
}
```

However I am not capturing the match. If I evaluate each of the match statements separately they do their job. So where am I going wrong with the statment?

I also tried

```
for (List<String> row : twoDim) {

                 if (tu2.matcher(row.get(0)).matches()) {

                     temp.add((ArrayList<List<String>>) twoDim);
                     System.out.println("Success"+temp.size());
                     for (ArrayList<String> t : temp) {
                         System.out.println(t+"Success");
                         if (tu2.matcher(temp.get(0).toString()).matches()) {
                             AcidExpMain.add((ArrayList<List<String>>) twoDim);
                             System.out.println("Success");
                         }
                     }

                 }
```

Comment: won't work for nested array though :- https://regex101.com/r/hA6mH2/1

Comment: I don't think its the regex that is the problem. I still get no matches with this

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate the structure and make the comparisons.

```
String[] rows = twoDim.split("[[");
for (String row : rows) {
String[] cols = row.split("[");
```

Then compare each of the columns to see whether the first word is Recumbent.